# Easiest way to sync two folders

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, mac, synchronization

What's the easiest way to sync the contents of a folder on a Mac OSX machine with another folder on a Linux server?

You can use `scp`:

```
scp -r /path/to/folder/ username@IP_ADDRESS:/path/to/sync/with
```

But `scp` is slow and copies all files, regardless of whether or not they exist on the server. What are some other options?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

install something like homebrew or macports to install rsync on the mac.. and use rsync

```
rsync -av /path/to/folder/ username@IP_ADDRESS:/path/to/sync/with
```

Comment: I am 99% sure that rsync has been included on OSX by default from since at least 10.2.  I am certain that it is present by default on 10.4 and above.  So unless he is running something insanely old, he has rsync already.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like unison fit the bill here?  It's sort of like rsync, but it allows two way synchronization.

Not sure if it's available on Mac OSX, but I'd think it would be..or could at least be built.